# Is there any way to work this keyword search functionality if we assign value directly without typing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have implemented a search functionality and it's working if we search the keyword by typing.

```
<input type="text" class="txtInput" id="searchTheKey" placeholder="Enter the keywords to search.....">
</label>
<ul id="matchKey">
<li id="subjectName">JavaScript</li>
<li id="teacherName"><a href="#">John Smith</a></li>
<li id="subjectName">Java</li>
<li id="teacherName"><a href="#">David Miller</a</li>
<li id="subjectName">MongoDB</li>
<li id="teacherName"><a href="#">Carol Taylor</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
   $("#searchTheKey").on('keyup', function(){
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#matchKey li").each(function () {
         if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
            $(this).prev('.subjectName').last().show();
         } else {
            $(this).hide();
         }
      });
   })
</script>
```

But in the case of assigning value in the input box directly, the search functionality is not working.

example : $(".txtInput").val("MongoDB");
is there any way to solve this issue, that this should work in both case.

Comment: Please note that you have multiple li's with the same id, Id must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.trigger("keyup")` to your `$(".txtInput").val("MongoDB")`

**Demo**

```js
$("#searchTheKey").on('keyup', function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#matchKey li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
      $(this).show();
      $(this).prev('.subjectName').last().show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
})

$(".mongo").click(function() {
  $(".txtInput").val("MongoDB").trigger("keyup")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="txtInput" id="searchTheKey" placeholder="Enter the keywords to search.....">

<ul id="matchKey">
  <li id="subjectName">JavaScript</li>
  <li id="teacherName"><a href="#">John Smith</a></li>
  <li id="subjectName">Java</li>
  <li id="teacherName"><a href="#">David Miller</a></li>
  <li id="subjectName">MongoDB</li>
  <li id="teacherName"><a href="#">Carol Taylor</a></li>
</ul>


<button class="mongo">search for mongo</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Relevant snippet:
 `$("#searchTheKey").on('keyup', function(){`

You bind your function on keyup, this way it won't execute since changing input value programmatically does not trigger a keyup event.

Easiest way would be to use `.trigger('keyup')` when you change the input value, like suggested by Carsten.